# Firebase/Firestore login with Facebook and Swift 4

Tags: swift, facebook, firebase

I am trying to make Facebook login work but I think documentation is super confusing and obsolete. These are steps I've made. I've created a Facebook app, added secret, key, and OAuth url.

This is my Podifle:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'App' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

  pod 'FacebookCore'
  pod 'FacebookLogin'
end
```

I have included this code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}
```

This is where it all should happen. This is my LoginViewController

```
import UIKit
import FacebookLogin

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [.publicProfile, .email])
        loginButton.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(loginButton)

        if AccessToken.current() {
            // User is logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoggedIn", sender: nil)
        }

    }

}
```

I have 2 errors. One is `Use of unresolved identifier 'AccessToken'` and other is crashing upon clicking `Continue with Facebook` button. Can somebody please help me sort this out?

Comment: It doesn't look like you completed the full [iOS guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login). If you'd like to see completed code, check out the [iOS quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/authentication/AuthenticationExampleSwift/MainViewController.swift#L125-L138)

Comment: Why do you use FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit?

Comment: It's required in [step 6a of the Facebook instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#6--add-facebook-login-to-your-code)

Comment: I followed Swift tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login 
The one you pointed out has only Obj-C code. Is there a Swift version that won't be deprecated?

Comment: The note at the top of the [Swift guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login) indicates that it's going to be deprecated soon (February 2018). Since Swift can [interop](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35) with Objective-C, it's fine to follow the Objective-C instructions

Comment: I removed Swift pods and code. But now I have this:

-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

And cryptic errors like this one. Also, I can't find how to extract email from login. Can you please point me to docs where they cover that?

Comment: Also, I am trying to wrap it up with Firebase and nothing works. It says FacebookAuthProvider is unresolved. I am following this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login

Comment: [FacebookAuthProvider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FacebookAuthProvider) is part of Firebase - did you `import Firebase`?

Comment: The easiest way to do auth with Firebase is to use [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/FirebaseAuthUI/README.md)

Comment: Thanks. I will try to use this instead.

Comment: Too bad. I started to implement code and their tutorial is obsolete. Nothing works.